# What happened in this solution of a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

I cannot see how this expression was simplified. Please help me see how! I tried Wolfram Alpha's step-by-step solution, but that only made me confused.

Comment: They factored out $x$ in both numerator and denominator.

Comment: @Mathematician42 How? :-)

Comment: $\sqrt{x}-2x=x(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-2)$ same for the other one, then divide the $x$'s.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{x}$, and use the fact that $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$

Comment: Surely the limit should be $x\to\infty$, not $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's easier, you can let $u=\sqrt x$. Then, assuming you mean $x\to\infty$ instead of $n\to\infty$, we get:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt x-2x}{4x+\sqrt x} = \lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u-2u^2}{4u^2+u} = \lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{1-2u}{4u+1}$$

Dividing top and bottom by $u$, the latter expression becomes

$$\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\frac1u-2}{4+\frac1u}$$

and then, since $1/u \to 0$ as $u \to \infty$, the limit is $-2/4 = -1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \sqrt x -2x = x \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt x} -2 \right) \quad \quad $ and $\displaystyle \quad \quad 4x+\sqrt x = x \left( 4 + \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \right)$